# Python Design Question - Concrete classes with different signature

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I have two classes with similar methods; however, there are some different mandatory parameters in one class.

e.g.

```
class NamespaceScoped:
    def get_object(self, name, namespace):
        pass
    def delete_object(self, name, namespace):
        pass

class ClusterScoped:
    def get_object(self, name):
        pass
    def delete_object(self, name):
        pass
```

I need to create an interface for the above classes. Since the methods are more or less the same, with only the signature varying a bit - is it a good design to have an Abstract class with the same operations but allow the implementation class to have a different signature?

e.g.

```
class InterfaceClient(ABC):
    def get_object(self, name):
        pass
    def delete_object(self, name):
        pass
```

In Pycharm - I get the warning that the signature is different for `class NamespaceScoped`.

I could technically do `**kwargs`, but I don't think I can enforce the mandatory parameters easily.

Is it an ok design to go with the above approach? An alternative to this is to have two abstract classes (one with namespace mandatory and the other with not); however, I see the declaration of the methods as are kind of duplicate.

Comment: If the second class just calls the first class with a namespace, it would make more sense as a child. Or perhaps a single class with an optional parameter `namespace="sensible-default"`.

Comment: If the function signatures are different, then you *can't* reasonably define a common interface for them…!? Work on the functions first so they actually have a common interface.

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for the suggestion - I thought about a single class but the amount of methods and functionality was quiet large - hence I wanted to divide the functionality based on scope (cluster vs namespaced - in namespace - the namespace param is mandatory and in cluster - it does not get used)

Comment: @deceze - yeah i m thinking its not good to do so - perhaps thinking of having two interface classes -one where the namespace is part of the param and in the other it is not part. 
My only concern is the methods are the same and hence "seem" like a future maintenance hassle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have one common interface, then I totally agree with the @deceze's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380748/python-design-question-concrete-classes-with-different-signature#comment133016517_75380748) above:

> You can't reasonably define a common interface if the signatures of the functions are different.

So you should make their signatures similar to each other.

From another point of view, both methods of the `InterfaceClient` are instance methods, the `NamespaceScoped` class can have a `namespace` member property (provided by the constructor or a setter method) by giving the ability to have one common interface for both `NamespaceScoped` and `ClusterScoped` classes.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class InterfaceClient(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_object(self, name):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def delete_object(self, name):
        pass


class NamespaceScoped(InterfaceClient):
    def __init__(self, namespace):
        self.namespace = namespace

    def get_object(self, name):
        pass

    def delete_object(self, name):
        pass


class ClusterScoped(InterfaceClient):
    def get_object(self, name):
        pass

    def delete_object(self, name):
        pass
```

Comment: thanks! this is quiet useful. I shall think along the above line - I initially thought about this but I wanted to also avoid using seperate instance NamespaceScoped for different namespace. However I can easily do a setter thinking about it now and then proceed to re-use the op.